# Can not boot up bare mental Raspberry binary to 0x80000

Tags: raspberry-pi3, u-boot, bare-metal

I want to boot up my bare-metal binary using u-boot with Raspberry Pi 3 Model B.
I used `fatload` command to load my binary to address `0x80000` but the result is CPU resetting

```
U-Boot> fatload mmc 0 0x80000 kernel8.elf
67168 bytes read in 16 ms (4 MiB/s)
```

Output:

```
U-Boot> bootelf 0x80000
"Synchronous Abort" handler, esr 0x96000004
elr: 00000000000d47c0 lr : 00000000000d480c (reloc)
elr: 000000003b3b47c0 lr : 000000003b3b480c
x0 : 0000000000000761 x1 : 0000000000080080
x2 : 0000000000000040 x3 : 000000000000003f
x4 : 0000000000080070 x5 : fffffffffffffff8
x6 : 00000000000001c5 x7 : 0000000000000010
x8 : 0000000000000044 x9 : 0000000000000008
x10: 0000000000000007 x11: 000000003af65b60
x12: 0000000000000000 x13: 0000000000000200
x14: 0000000000080000 x15: 00000000ffffffff
x16: 0000000000004110 x17: 940c47087de197f0
x18: 000000003af5bdd0 x19: 10000060d5244080
x20: 0000000000080000 x21: 0000000000000002
x22: 000000003af72890 x23: 0000000000000000
x24: 0000000000000002 x25: 0000000000000000
x26: 0000000000000000 x27: 0000000000000000
x28: 000000003af728f0 x29: 000000003af5bac0

Code: d65f03c0 f9401693 8b130293 8b151a73 (f9400660) 
Resetting CPU ...

resetting ...
```

In linker file I already setup `. = 0x80000`

```
 SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x80000;
    .text.boot : { *(.text.boot) }
    .text : { *(.text) }
    .rodata : { *(.rodata) }
    .data : { *(.data) }
    . = ALIGN(0x8);
    bss_begin = .;
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } 
    bss_end = .;
}
```

Anyone can tell me the possible address to load binary?

Answer (score -1):

I've found the answer:

To boot up the image with uboot, I need to convert the binary to uboot binary format and place the binary at `0x00100000` to ensure it does not conflict with uboot binary

```
mkimage -A arm64 -C none -O linux -T kernel -d kernel8.img -a 0x00100000 -e 0x00100000 kernel8.uimg
```

Useful resource:
https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/hello-world-for-bare-metal-arm-using-qemu/